# How to get a dual boot USB drive to work in Vista

Tags: 10.04, dual-boot, windows-vista

Hey I managed with the help of a friend to get 10.04 onto a 2TB WD USB drive for dual boot but it doesn't want to work on my Vista loaded laptop. Is there a fix? i don't have the choice of erasing Vista. The drive works on another Ubuntu laptop. I have yet to try it on my dad's XP machine.

Answer (score 2):

With some laptops, plug the USB drive in *then* turn on the power. Press `F2` or `Delete` to enter the PC BIOS settings.

The setting you want is usually under the BOOT section (use left/right arrow keys to change sections) and check the boot device order, make sure USB is before hard drive.

If you are unsure about changing anything, have a look and write down what options you see, exit without saving and let us know what options there is.

Answer (score 1):

First,is the usb drive bootable, and did you select it at boot time from the BIOS boot screen ? Have you set the BIOS to put the USB drive first, or do you select from a menu each time you boot?

If you enter your BIOS, and move USB to the top of the boot order, it should select the USB Hard drive automatically at boot up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have grub installed on the USB drive, you can boot unsupported operating systems (such as windows) by chain loading.  Find your way to the grub command prompt and enter these commands:

```
grub> rootnoverify (hd0,0)
grub> makeactive
grub> chainloader +1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Computer(s) you are tying to run Ubuntu on may not support booting from USB. If this is the case either update your BIOS or get a new Computer. If it is compatible then check the boot menu which varies from PC so look for the key Combination for "Boot Menu" or "Boot Select" at startup. If I works you should be able to see the 2TB drive.